# Good alternative for thread.sleep (for a users session)

Tags: c#, multithreading, session

cCan anyone suggest a anternative for thread.sleep for a users session? I have looked it up and the only suggestion was a Monitor.Wait method, is that the best you can do? Sorry for the short content in the question but there really isn't much to say. I HAVE researched but nothing applies to using it for a users session.. only other stuff like consoles

I need something that will stop the current session not all the sessions.

Comment: Why do you need to sleep in the session? Can you explain what the operation is that you need the sleep for? Thread.Sleep has very few legitimate uses, especially to pause a UI or something.

Comment: What kind of "session" you mean in "current session not all the sessions"? Adding framework tag (WinFroms, console, Asp.Net, or something else...) could clarify that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a Timer?

System.Timers.Timer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This won't block the UI thread and will call a method you supply after the specified time.